# Bootstrap-Vue, show tooltip on condition

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

Using Bootstrap-Vue (vue2).
When clicking on a div, I need to show a tooltip only if isDisabled=true

```
<div id="disabled-wrapper" class="includeExclude" :class="{ disabled: isDisabled }" 
@click="excludeCountry" tabindex="0">
<b-tooltip v-if="isDisabled" variant="secondary" target="disabled-wrapper" triggers="click">
</b-tooltip>
```

this is the method that fires on clicking the div

```
excludeCountry(){
      if (this.temporaryFilters['countries'] != undefined){
        this.isDisabled = true;
      }
      else {
        this.operator = 'notin';
        this.exclude = !this.exclude;
      }
    }
```

I cannot get the v-if condition to work, If I remove it, the tooltip works fine clicking on the element

the part

```
 if (this.temporaryFilters['countries'] != undefined){
        this.isDisabled = true;
      }
```

works because I have some logs on this.isDisabled and it changes to true

Comment: Your code is correct. Only one reason why tooltip is not show is condition `this.temporaryFilters['countries'] != undefined`.

Comment: that part is correct, because "this.isDisabled = true" works, but the tooltip doesn't show up

Answer (score 0):

```
this.temporaryFilters['countries'] !== undefined
```

You can update the condition like this and try.

Answer (score 0):

If condition works and `this.isDisabled` is  `true`, you can see tooltip after second click. `v-if` works correct.

If you want to see tooltip after first click you must add Event Modifier `.capture`. Example: `@click.capture="excludeCountry"`
[Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers),
[Demo](http://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-bassi-t3rez)